# Height of Javascript canvas with scrolling

Tags: javascript, canvas, height

I'm making a snow effect on my forum bloodstainedfanforums.com

I'm using a canvas Javascript element with the width and height controlled by
window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth

I would like the snow to continue down the page, but it is only vertically as large as the initial window. If the canvas is resized it will interrupt the animation.

What's the best way to extend that canvas down the entire page initially?

Thank you, and happy holidays.

Comment: have you tried setting the canvas to be the size of scrollHeight instead of innerHeight? then it will extend to the entire page

Comment: What element includes the header body and footer? Sorry, I'm pretty new to coding. Window.scrollHeight didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `document.body.scrollHeight` instead of `window.innerHeight`